# Is a firewall saying "DNS server settings changed" when connecting to public WiFi cause for concern?

Tags: wireless-networking, dns, firewall

What does it mean when a firewall says that a new WiFI network connection has caused the DNS server settings to change? What should a regular end-user be aware of, and are there circumstances under which it should be treated as a concern?

---

Due to current circumstances I need to use public WiFi a lot, in cafes and similar.

I have the firewall [Glasswire](https://www.glasswire.com) installed, and sometimes when connecting to WiFi it pops up a message like:

> DNS server settings changed. New: `192.168.1.X` Old: `fecX:X:X:XXXX:X`

(`X`s are numbers)

I'm not entirely clear what the meaning of this is - particularly, why it happens on some networks and not others. I know there are risks to using public WiFi, so I'd like to know if DNS server settings changing on connecting is something normal I can safely ignore, something suspicious that means I should disconnect or take other action, or something where I should make other enquiries first.

The 192.168.1.X IP address looks (to my non-expert eye) like a normal wireless router IP address. Is this message essentially just saying, "This wireless router has a different network address to the last one you used"? If so, would I be right in thinking that's perfectly normal and safe?

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry about it.

In most cases, DNS servers will accept queries only from certain networks. And when connecting to a new network (this wifi), the network provides you with a DNS server. That's why you get this warning.

If you are worried, you could always use Google servers: 8.8.8.8.
However, this wouldn't prevent some other attacks, so in general, do not worry, just be aware you are on a public wifi network.
(That also means that lots of people nearby could see your Internet traffic).